# How to change image during a scroll on Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, imageview

I'm a beginner on Android development and am trying to build my first app. I have an activity with a round target image and I'd like to make this image vanish at scroll down and display an another image instead that would snap to the toolBar (see the example images below).

I've researched this, but have only found information about using effects in apps where the image just vanishes. Perhaps, the Coordinator Layout could be useful here?

[Initial state of my layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwnwb.png)

After scrolling up, I want to change to a [state like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTlSL.png).

To summarize, I have to :
- make my round Image go behind de ToolBar
- make the rectangular ImageView2 appear below the ToolBar
- Align my buttons (I guess it's about speed ? The one in the middle should go faster or something like that).
- Display new infos coming from below

Answer (score 0):

You should surely use CoordinatorLayout. The point is that you should add custom behavior to your ImageView.
You can see an example here:
https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/customizing-coordinatorlayouts-behavior/

Comment: What about the buttons ? The middle one should scroll up faster to get to the top at the same time as the other buttons. Maybe a parallax like effect would do the job but I have no idea how to implement it !